# Grouping lists by their first elements and deleting some groups

Tags: list-manipulation, gathering

I have a list

```
{{1, 4, 1, -3}, {1, 4, 1, -1}, {1, 4, 2, -2}, {1, 5, 2, -4}, {1, 5, 
  2, -1}, {1, 5, 4, -3}, {1, 5, 4, -2}, {1, 6, 3, -5}, {1, 6, 
  3, -1}, {1, 7, 4, -6}, {1, 7, 4, -1}, {1, 8, 5, -7}, {1, 8, 
  5, -1}, {2, 5, 1, -1}, {2, 7, 1, -3}, {2, 7, 3, -1}, {2, 7, 
  4, -2}, {2, 9, 2, -4}, {2, 9, 5, -1}, {3, 6, 1, -1}, {3, 7, 
  2, -1}, {3, 8, 2, -2}, {3, 8, 3, -1}, {3, 9, 4, -2}, {3, 9, 
  4, -1}, {3, 10, 1, -3}, {3, 10, 5, -1}, {4, 7, 1, -1}, {4, 9, 
  3, -1}, {5, 8, 1, -1}, {5, 9, 2, -1}, {5, 10, 3, -1}, {6, 9, 
  1, -1}, {7, 10, 1, -1}}
```

In the list there are some sets have first three elements equal. For exmaple, `{1, 4, 1, -3}` and `{1, 4, 1, -1}`. With two this sets, I want to have `{1, 4, 1, -3, -1}`. How can I get like that for all sets in list? After that, remove the sets have four elements.

Comment: `With[{gb = GatherBy[#, #[[;; 3]] &]},
  Flatten /@ 
   Transpose[{gb[[All, 1, ;; 3]], Flatten /@ gb[[All, All, 4 ;;]]}]] &@list`

Comment: `Join[#[[1, ;; 3]], Flatten@#[[All, 4 ;;]]] & /@ GatherBy[list, #[[;; 3]] &]`

Comment: Does your list have sets of length 4 only?

Comment: @ciao and JHM Please see update.

Comment: `Join[#[[1, ;; 3]], Flatten@#[[All, 4 ;;]]] & /@ 
 DeleteCases[GatherBy[list, #[[;; 3]] &], {_List}]`

Comment: I want to keep the sets of length 5. Forexample `{1, 4, 1, -3, -1}`

Comment: I mean, does your input list consist only of sets of length 4, like the example in your post?

Comment: You understood me. Thank you very much. You can post your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where `list` is your list,

```
Join[#[[1, ;; 3]], Flatten@#[[All, 4 ;;]]] & /@ 
 DeleteCases[GatherBy[list, #[[;; 3]] &], {_List}]

(* {{1, 4, 1, -3, -1}, {1, 5, 2, -4, -1}, {1, 5, 4, -3, -2}, {1, 6, 
  3, -5, -1}, {1, 7, 4, -6, -1}, {1, 8, 5, -7, -1}, {3, 9, 4, -2, -1}} *)
```

Modifying @ciao 's code:

```
With[{gb = DeleteCases[GatherBy[#, #[[;; 3]] &], {_List}]}, 
   Flatten /@ 
    Transpose[{gb[[All, 1, ;; 3]], 
      Flatten /@ gb[[All, All, 4 ;;]]}]] &@list

(* {{1, 4, 1, -3, -1}, {1, 5, 2, -4, -1}, {1, 5, 4, -3, -2}, {1, 6, 
  3, -5, -1}, {1, 7, 4, -6, -1}, {1, 8, 5, -7, -1}, {3, 9, 4, -2, -1}} *)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
KeyValueMap[
   If[Length[#2] == 1, Nothing, Join[##]] &
] @  GroupBy[data, Most -> Last]
```

> ```
>  {{1, 4, 1, -3, -1}, {1, 5, 2, -4, -1}, {1, 5, 4, -3, -2}, {1, 6, 
>    3, -5, -1}, {1, 7, 4, -6, -1}, {1, 8, 5, -7, -1}, {3, 9, 4, -2, -1}}
> ```

Comment: `Nothing` seems like something I will use (pun intended) +1 :)